# setinterval not able to run document.writeln

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Greetings,

The code below works for alert but doesn't for document.writeln. Is it because of the onload event? If so shouldn't the browser be able to add more elements after it's finished loading? - Trying to understand how it works (I am studying jquery in the meantime).

```
<body onload="timeMsg()">
<script type="text/javascript">
        function timeMsg()
        {
        var t=self.setInterval("randInt()",3000);
        }
        function randInt()
        { 
        document.writeln("<br />" +Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)); //doesn't work
        alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));  //works

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use document.writeln anyway. This function is doomed to fail.

Comment: What would be an alternative to this function? Thanks!

Comment: `<div id="content"></div>` in the body. This in the JS: `document.getElementById("content").html(myCode);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative

```
<body onload="timeMsg()">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function timeMsg()
    {
        var t = self.setInterval("randInt()", 3000);
    }

    function randInt()
    { 
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML += "<br />" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));  //works
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works in Chrome. Maybe you should follow [MDC's advice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.write):

> Writing to a document that has already loaded without calling `document.open()` will automatically perform a document.open call. Once you have finished writing, it is recommended to call `document.close()`, to tell the browser to finish loading the page.

*Edit: As @Pointy points out (nice sentence ;)), this will replace the whole content of the page.*

And one more thing: `document.write` is not available in XHTML documents!

Conclusion: **Don't use it.**

You could achieve the same effect by e.g.

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<br />" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
```

or

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)));

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: ... but won't the writes after the page is done cause the whole thing to be blown away? The question alludes to "adding elements" ...

Comment: @Pointy: Indeed with `document.open` and `.close` it replaces the whole content. But still, without it, it works in Chrome ;)

Comment: Kudos for doing it without using `innerHTML`.  +1

Comment: ....i checked ie and firefox and didn't work. so basically i must append new children to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Once the browser has finished reading a complete HTML page, the "document" is closed. Calling `document.write()` (or its friends) after that point will implicitly re-open the document and **obliterate** everything that's there.

Instead of that, you can use DOM manipulation APIs to update the page.

Comment: In jQuery: `$('body').append('<br />' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));`

Comment: correct but how come it works in chrome? Felix King is right I tested it and there it works so not sure ...

Comment: Well I'm not really sure - maybe it has to do with when/if an implicit "close()" is done on the document between timer events?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing to the document, inject elements into the DOM:

```
var el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
el.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7));
```